# Is there an efficent way to rearange lists of lists where transposing the whole list is no option?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

I have a list of lists of lists, listing pairs of pairings. {{{a,b},{c,d}},{{a,e},{f,g}},....}
I want to apply a function to this list that gives me a 4 level list where each first level element becomes a list of the original first level element and its Counterfactual:

{{a,b},{c,d}} -> {{{a,b},{c,d}},{{a,d},{c,b}}.

That means the second elements of the lowest level lists should swap place.

I have come up with the following:

```
Transpose[{#,Transpose[{{#[[All, 1, 1]], #[[All, 2, 2]]}, {#[[All, 2, 1]], #[[All, 1, 2]]}}, {2, 3, 1}]}] &@ myList
```

This works, but it is rather slow. Also the list I want to apply this to, grows exponentially with the n in the overall program and I am applying this function several hundred times, so even small efficiency gains would really pay of.

I feel like there should be a way to make 2 numbers swap places in under several hours even if I need to do it 1.5 million times.

Comment: Are the `a` `b` etc, a specific type? Integer, Real, etc?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: a,b,c... are integers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Transpose` is not a bad thing per se. Nonetheless, here are a couple of faster alternatives:

```
F1 = Transpose[{#, Transpose[{{#[[All, 1, 1]], #[[All, 2, 2]]}, {#[[All, 2, 1]], #[[All, 1, 2]]}}, {2, 3, 1}]}] &;
F2 = Map[
   A |-> {A, {{A[[1, 1]], A[[2, 2]]}, {A[[2, 1]], A[[1, 2]]}}}];
F3 = Module[{result},
    result = Transpose[{#, #}];
    result[[All, 2, {1, 2}, 2]] = result[[All, 2, {2, 1}, 2]];
    result
    ] &;
F4 = Compile[{{A, _Integer, 2}},
   {
    {
     {Compile`GetElement[A, 1, 1], Compile`GetElement[A, 1, 2]},
     {Compile`GetElement[A, 2, 1], Compile`GetElement[A, 2, 2]}
     },
    {
     {Compile`GetElement[A, 1, 1], Compile`GetElement[A, 2, 2]},
     {Compile`GetElement[A, 2, 1], Compile`GetElement[A, 1, 2]}
     }
    },
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];

F5 = With[{
    A =
     Transpose[
      D[
       {{{a, b}, {c, d}}, {{a, d}, {c, b}}},
       {Flatten[{{a, b}, {c, d}}], 1}
       ],
      {2, 3, 4, 1}
      ]
    },
   ArrayReshape[#, {Length[#], 4}] . A &
   ];
```

Usage examples with timings:

```
n = 1000000;
myList = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {n, 2, 2}];

result1 = F1[myList]; // RepeatedTiming // First
result2 = F2[myList]; // RepeatedTiming // First
result3 = F3[myList]; // RepeatedTiming // First
result4 = F4[myList]; // RepeatedTiming // First
result5 = F5[myList]; // RepeatedTiming // First
result1 == result2 == result3 == result4 == result5
```

> 1.20759
>
> 0.347046
>
> 0.0849625
>
> 0.0580747
>
> 0.0935506
>
> True

`F4` is also parallelized. Using a 4-Core processor here. However, it does not help much because the task is memory bound. Nonetheless, is should scale nicely with `n`. For `n = 10000000` (ten million), it does the job in under a second.

I particularly like `F5` because it is basically a no-brainer once you realize that the output depends linearly on the input. So simple differentiation with `D` generates the transformation matrix. We just have to take care of transposing it correctly...

In general, I would strongly advice against this transformation in the first place because it just doubles the size of the data set (and memory bandwidth is precious) without adding any valuable information *that could not be computed on the fly*. Be assured that 99% of the runtime of `F4` is spend for moving the data from RAM to the L1 cache and back. Only 1% of runtime is spend for the actual "calculation". So the best approach will be to fuse all numeric computations on each of the matrices in the data set into one `CompiledFunction` so that the data has to be showeled into the CPU only once.